# Correctly storing the list of items in db and then printing them item by item using jinja, flask and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, flask, jinja2, multi-select

Newbie here. I have recently started learning coding and trying to build a webapp from scratch using Flask, Jinja and PostgreSQL.

I am using a multi-select input to store a list of strengths in a field that I want to later print item by item.

```
Strengths = ['Communication','Teamwork']
```

Here is what I have done:
**init.py**

```
class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    strengths = db.Column(db.String(10000))
```

**form.html**

```
<select
    class="form-select"
    id="strengths"
    name="strengths"
    multiple
    data-allow-clear="true"
    data-suggestions-threshold="0"
    data-show-all-suggestions="true"
  >
    <option disabled hidden value="">Choose a skill to endorse...</option>
    {% for skill in skills %}
    <option value="{{skill.label}}">{{skill.label}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

**views.py**

```
strengths = request.form.getlist('strengths')
print(strengths)
new_note = Note(strengths=strengths)
```

The above print statement works fine and shows the outpur as expected `['Communication','Teamwork']`

However, when I try to print this in jinja using `{{Strengths}}`, I see this as the output `{Communication,Teamwork}`

Checking the postgreSQL db, I see that the list is stored as printed by jinja `{Communication,Teamwork}`.

How can I make sure I can store the list in a way that I can print the first strength by using `{{strengths[0]}}`?

TIA

Comment: Because you store the data as String in Postgres. Either you trust the data in your database and you convert string to array with python, or you use the ARRAY type from postgres https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY.

Comment: Hey @Victor, can't seem to make it work. I tried updating the code to 
strengths = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.String,1))

but the data is still stored as a character string like {Communication,Teamwork} instead of [Communication,Teamwork]

Anything obvious I am missing?